# Hosting and accessing my server behind a router?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I'm testing a network library called enet. When I make connections on port 1720 using 192.168. IPs, my laptop (client) connects to my PC (host) no problem. When I connect my PC with PPPOE and use the new IP (76.86...) then I never get anything.

I've tried forwarding port 1720 to the PC,forwarding it to the laptop, using DMZ, nothing at all works. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: With what are you doing portforwarding?  What is providing the pppoe connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you inside the network when you are trying to connect using the 76.86... address.  You can't connect to your own network using a real world address from inside that same network.  If you want to know if you have to port opened properly on the router, modem, firewall, etc go to canyouseeme.org and put in your port number (1720) and it will tell you if you have the port open correctly.  Then you just need to forward it correctly and test it from outside the network.